# FireZenk AudioWaves

Tags: android

I am trying to use this library in my project :

https://github.com/FireZenk/AudioWaves

But app crashes.

```
audioVisualizer=(Visualizer) findViewById(R.id.audioVisualizer);

////

public void onRecordButtonClick(View view) {

   verySimpleMediaRecorderSetUp();
   audioVisualizer.startListening();
}
```

The crash happens just because that visualizer view is in the xml file for this activity. When I remove the view , recording works fine. But I would like to use this view so I'm looking for a proper way to use this library.

Comment: can you give us the stacktrace?

Comment: Hello , I will in a few hours. The error is about IllegalStateException at mediaRecorder.start();.

Comment: You need to provide your stacktrace. Seems like your activity in which your view is being held is been killed hence, illegalStateException. Can't confirm without the stacktrace.

Comment: Instead of audioVisualizer.startListening(); try this: ((Visualizer) findViewById(R.id.visualizer)).startListening();

Comment: Also, try it before calling method verySimpleMediaRecorderSetUp();

Comment: @NougatLover Im not the best with Java but , arent they basically the same thing ? Your first comment