# android studio logcat going crazy

Tags: android-studio

When I start my app , logcat starts showing too many logs. Like it shows everything going on with the connected device. Before when this happened , restarting android studio used to fix this but it doesn't work anymore. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are not filtering logs of your App. On the right side of the LogCat, there is a dropdown in which select "Show only selected application" instead of "No Filters".

FYI: In case the selected option is "No Filters", Your logcat will explode with system logs that are running on your phone from the background processes , other background Apps , system applications etc.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also check this question please?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199895/firezenk-audiowaves